# how to pass marker parameter to maps.google.com in get request

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

hi i want to open my current location in maps.google.com . currently i can pass my latitude and longitude variables and and zoom level and create the map like this

http://maps.google.com/?ll=6.9319,79.8478&z=9

but i want to add a marker to my current position . i looked for many answers like

http://querystring.org/google-maps-query-string-parameters/

but did not help me , please help................

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using this:

[http://maps.google.com/**?q=Some+Name@6.9319,79.8478**&z=9](http://maps.google.com/?q=Some%20Name@6.9319,79.8478&z=9)

But it is not guaranteed to work all of the time.  Should work most of the time.